# TigerText simplest text conversation app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, messaging

I downloaded TigerText Demo app from [here](http://github.com/tigerconnect/ios-app-messenger-demo) and I opened it in xcode but its a huge app I just need conversation part or that single viewcontorller no need of login because I will pass that hard coded like this.

```
[[TTKit sharedInstance] loginWithUserId:@"username" password:@"password" 

  success:^(TTUser *user) { 
    // Handle login. 
  } failure:^(NSError *error) { 
    // Handle failure. 
  }];
```

After that there will be only one view where users will see there msgs. no login and not organization views required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display messages in 'ConversationViewController' you will first need  a TTRosterEntry object (An object that represents a conversation), if you would like to load all TTRosterEntry objects regardless of their organization you can use this api

```
NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[TTKit sharedInstance] rosterFetchControllerForAllOrganizationsWithDelegate:self];
NSArray *rostersForAllOrganizations = [frc fetchedObjects];
```

Once you select a roster you can load 'ConversationViewController'

```
ConversationViewController *conversation =  [GetAppDelegate.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ConversationViewController"];
conversation.rosterEntry = rosterEntry;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:conversation animated:YES];
```